# Custom UIwindow not display

Tags: objective-c, statusbar, uiwindow

I'm trying to create a new window for Custom alert on rootViewController.

```
- (void)viewdidAppear
{
            UIWindow *newWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
            newWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1.0f;
            newWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            newWindow.hidden = NO;
```

`UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        newWindow.rootViewController = vc;

        [newWindow makeKeyAndVisible];`

But the newWindow not working. I am confused with this strange question.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Where is that code, please? Show the context. Explain what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: @matt i want create custom new window add myapp.but  not work...

Comment: But the correct way to make a custom alert is to use a presented view controller. That is what you should be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is window set Global variable.
When Window makeKeyAndVisible,window was not be released.