# iOS: why the UIWindow not show?

Tags: ios, swift

why the UIWindow not show?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
    let win = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        win.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        win.windowLevel = .alert
        win.isHidden = false
        win.makeKeyAndVisible()
   
    }

}
```

I can't see the window.

I have already read this [Custom UIWindow not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892487/custom-uiwindow-not-showing)

I think it is easy, I just missed it.

Comment: Cool, `view.addSubview(win)` did it

Comment: Hey, I have run your code. It works perfectly without any changes.

Comment: I use MBP ， mac OS 10.15.5, Xcode 11.6, which is painful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `win` to `self.view`.

```
view.addSubview(win)
```